# Novice Set-Theory Operation Questions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Hello StackExchange users.

I have arrived on the website today to ask questions involving the relevance of critical Set-Theory operations. Please assist me with the process.

My interpretation of a valid "binary" operation on a given set is that it merely requires the two operands and the output value(s) of the function to be elements within the specified set(Hence "closure" is established).

Suppose that we are operating on set $S$, an infinite set containing all of the subsets of set $\mathbb{Z}$, which is the set of all integer quantities.

Well, given my naivety involving the subject, I would like to determine if the union of two given subsets within set $S$ is a permissible binary operation.

My rationale is that as both operand sets are elements of set $S$, it is valid given that the resulting set, $C$, is also a subset of set $S$(And thenceforth "closed" as a direct result).

Is this an accurate deduction? I believe that I am somewhat mistaken.

Comment: You're not mistaken, very much on the right track. Just a couple of corrections, fine points: in order to guarantee that $S$ is closed under $\cup$, you probably mean that $S = \mathcal{P}(\Bbb Z)$, not (as you stated) that $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb Z)\subseteq S$. (If $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb Z) \subsetneqq S$ or $S \subsetneqq \mathcal{P}(\Bbb Z)$ then $S$ might **not** be closed under $\cup$.) So assume that. Then if $X,Y\in S$, you mean that $X\cup Y$ is **a member of** $S$, not "is also a subset" of $S$. It's also a subset of $\Bbb Z$, so if $S$ is the powerset of $\Bbb Z$ then that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that works. Note that this operation makes sense on the power set of *any* set, not only $\mathbb{Z}$. Other binary operations on power sets include the intersection and the symmetric difference. Interestingly enough, these latter two operations make any power set into a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring), that is, a special kind of algebraic structure.